# It's ok to allocate a pointer of one type and dispose it as a different type but of the same size?

Tags: delphi, pointers, types

It's ok to allocate a pointer of one type and dispose it as a different type but of the same size ? I mean like this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var A:PInt64;   // 64bit
    P:Pointer;
    B:PDouble;  // 64bit
begin
  New(A);
  P:=A;
  B:=P;
  Dispose(B);
end;
```

Let's say I want this only for 8, 16, 32, 64bit signed and unsigned types. It's ok ?

Comment: An object lesson in how to write unmaintainable code!

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's maintainable or not, I want to know only if it's working, if it's allocated and disposed the same memory location... I really need to do this.

Comment: Fine, but when you discover a memory leak in 18 months time ...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's leaking if I do that ? The pointers are of the same size.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not saying that at all.

Comment: @MarusNebunu -- yes, there are no memory leak. Btw, are you using ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True; ?

Comment: @Zam, I wasn't saying there is!  Just questioning what's likely to be made of code like this when it's revisited.

Comment: @MartynA -- yes, you right, I am sorry.

Comment: I would like to see the real usage of this. It points to something suspicious. An interesting question though.

Comment: Where can I upload the source code to show you ? I think it's too big to post it here...

Comment: This will work because the memory manager knows the size it must release, and since these are not managed types, there is no extra finalization required. It will not work for managed types (i.e. types that require extra initialization or finalization by the runtime code). So generally, I would only recommend using the right pointer, not some other type. Code that does something like this has an ***extreme code smell***.

Comment: The way you've pitched this question actually makes me wonder if you're aware of [variant records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records)? It seems you want a single variable to hold 2 different kinds of data that will overlap. Variant records would allow you to do this safely.

Comment: Yes, but they say variants are slower...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the type being pointed at is not a managed type then this is safe. In your case, neither `Int64` nor `Double` are managed types and so this is safe.

An example of a managed type would be a String, interface, Variant, anonymous procedure/method, a record containing managed types, etc.

When you use `New` and `Dispose` on a managed type, the object must be initialized and finalized.  When you use `New` and `Dispose` on an unmanaged type, it is equivalent to calling `GetMem` and `FreeMem`.

In fact, you don't need the types being pointed at to be the same size. When the call to `FreeMem` is made, the size of the type is not passed. The memory being pointed at has metadata for each block that allows it to deallocate the entire block.

Comment: Yes, I was reffering to unmanged types. I did not know that they are called so. AnsiChar and WideChar are managed ?

Comment: @"your last phrase" - So maybe that's way I don't receive memory leakage report if I set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=True` and allocate a PDouble and dispose it as a PByte...

Comment: +1  Something about this whole question feels a bit like BASE jumping... whilst there is an illuminating thrill in discovering that one *can* indeed leap from a precipice dressed as a squirrel and land safely at the intended destination, the shocking recklessness of actually witnessing it being done forces a deep introspection into the wisdom of selecting over all others this particular means of getting the job done.

Comment: While it may work, I would certainly never recommend to Dispose a PInt64 as a PDouble. I would generally say that one should only Dispose on the right type. Disposing on the wrong type is a terrible code smell, IMO.